# Как настроить QLineEdit что бы он принимал только числа.

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

Я хочу что бы пользователь вводил в QLineEdit только числа.

Где в настройках QLineEdit-а свойства для приёма только чисел ??

Этот вопрос, перевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422995/set-qlineedit-to-accept-only-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QLineEdit::setValidator()
```

для примера:

```
myLineEdit->setValidator( new QIntValidator(0, 100, this) );
```

или

```
myLineEdit->setValidator( new QDoubleValidator(0, 100, 2, this) )
```

Посмотри : QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator, QLineEdit::setValidator

---

Можно использовать   QSpinBox.

А для значений с плавающей точкой  QDoubleSpinBox.

```
QSpinBox myInt;
myInt.setMinimum(-5);
myInt.setMaximum(5);
myInt.setSingleStep(1);// увеличит текущее значение на  1 (если вы используете клавишу  "стрелка вверх") (если вы нажмете клавишу "стрелка вниз " то  => -1)
myInt.setValue(2);// по умолчанию/начальное значение 
myInt.value();// получаем текущее значение
//connect(&myInt, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(myValueChanged(int)));
```

---

Вы можете установить маску ввода (InputMask):

```
 QLineEdit.setInputMask("9")
```

Это позволяет пользователю ввести только одну цифру от 0 до 9. Используйте несколько девяток, чтобы позволить пользователю ввести многозначное число (к примеру:999).Также посмотрите документацию InputMask и уведите полный список символов которые можно использовать для редактирования ввода.

(мой ответ на питоне но может он работает в С++)

---

Почему бы не установить QSpinBox для этой цели ?? Вы можете скрыть кнопки "вверх/вниз" невидимыми с помощью следующего кода:

```
/ ...
QSpinBox* spinBox = new QSpinBox( this );
spinBox->setButtonSymbols( QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons ); // после этого выглядит как QLineEdit.
//...
```

*прим. переводчика: как по мне этот вариант стандартный не удобный костыль, лучше пользоваться  setValidator*

---

Если вы используете QT Creator 5.6, вы можете поступить так:

```
#include <QIntValidator>

ui->myLineEditName->setValidator( new QIntValidator);
```

Я рекомендую вам поставить эту строку после

```
 ui->setupUi(this);
```

Надеюсь, это поможет.

---

*прим. переводчика: Сам пользуюсь двумя способами :*

```
 ui->lE_CycleTime->setValidator(new QIntValidator); // в QT Creator 5.6, вы можете сделать это вот так. (сейчас)
 ui->lE_CycleTime->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\\.|,)[0-9]{2}"), this)); // числа до двух точек после запятой.
  // (раньше использовал этот код, писал тогда в qt4.8)
```

Comment: `setValidator( new QIntValidator);` — даёт утечку, как на enSO уже заметили....

Comment: Нужно указать ему `parent`, как это сделано в первом примере. Тогда сам Qt позаботится об освобождении памяти.

Comment: @maestro, так там парентом указан this, получается валидатор удалится вместе с основным классом, не правильнее ли родителем указывать тот же контрол, для которого устанавливается валидатор? вот так `myLineEdit->setValidator( new QIntValidator(0, 100, myLineEdit) );`

Comment: @goldstar_labs, да, так будет правильнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от себя

Только сейчас заметил что всё таки QIntValidator и QDoubleValidator не доделан ;_; .

Надо было ввести 13 значное число без знаков после запятой.

QIntValidator позволял мне ввести Только 10 значное число  (превратить его в long int либо long long int увы я несмог)

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(ui->lineEdit)); // либо  new QIntValidator(this)  
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString inputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "inputText :" << inputText;
    double zapros = inputText.toDouble();
    qDebug() << "zapros :" << zapros;
}
```

И почему то реагировал на пробел :(

```
inputText : "242 324 4"
zapros : 0
inputText : "242324"
zapros : 242324
```

QDoubleValidator повёл себя чуть лучше, но также "бестолково" реагировал на пробел

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator(0,1000000000000000,0,this));  
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString inputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "inputText :" << inputText;
    double zapros = inputText.toDouble();
    qDebug() << "zapros :" << zapros;
}
```

вот вывод:

```
inputText : "45535 352324,"
zapros : 0
inputText : "45535352324,"
zapros : 0
inputText : "45535352324"
zapros : 4.55354e+10
```

так что пока пользуюсь

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^([1-9][0-9]*|0)"), this));
```

вот вывод

```
inputText : "123323213133333333333222222222"
zapros : 1.23323e+29
```